# Call id in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm working in jquery now. I did put each of my id uniuqe. but now i have no idea on how to call the id using onclick function jquery.

```
while ($i < $num3b) {  
    $staff_name=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"staff_name");  
    echo '<br/><span id="link'.$i.'" style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;">'.$staff_name. $i.'</span>';
    echo '<span id="linkmsg" style="width:100%;float:left;display:none;">OK</span>';
$i++;
}
```

Here my jquery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var linkid = $('#id').val();
    var link = '#link'+linkid;
    $(link).click(function() {
        jQuery('#linkmsg').show(); 
    });
});
```

Thanks you for helping.

Comment: Why are you appending value to the id ?

Comment: Why do you append value to id?

Comment: i tought id should be unique. So i put the value. Otherwise i don't know how to call the id in my jquery. since it's a looping process, and each of the data have the text link so that they can click to show the 'OK' text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead of id as other folks mentioned here. If you can't then you can use [`attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Try:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("span[id^='link']").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings("span[id^='linkmsg']").show(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I still see it. `$(span...)` the parameter should be a string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `id` here you can use class attribute to solve this issue. Also the id `linkmsg` was not unique

Try

```
while ($i < $num3b) {  
    $staff_name=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"staff_name");  
    echo '<br/><span class="link" id="link'.$i.'" style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;">'.$staff_name. $i.'</span>';
    echo '<span class="linkmsg" id="linkmsg'.$i.'" style="width:100%;float:left;display:none;">OK</span>';
$i++;
}
```

then

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.linlk').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next('.linkmsg').show(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use class.

```
while ($i < $num3b) {  
    $staff_name=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"staff_name");  
    echo '<br/><span class="link" style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;">'.$staff_name. $i.'</span>';
    echo '<span id="linkmsg" style="width:100%;float:left;display:none;">OK</span>';
$i++;
}


$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".link").click(function() {
        $(this).find("#linkmsg").show(); 
    });
});
```